# Set up a development environment for Addon development for mozilla firefox using Addon-SDK and an IDE

Tags: eclipse, firefox, netbeans-7, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

i want to create a mozilla firefox addon using Addon-SDK method. I had been browsing for a way to set up a development environment using an IDE(Netbeans, Eclipse, etc.) for this. But I ended up unsuccessful. I even checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials#development-techniques for a solution. But no luck. Can anyone help me and explain how to set this up ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no IDE that will launch a Firefox extension. You need to use a command line tool to do so ([`cfx`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started) or [`jpm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29)).

Then you can use the same to launch it using the `run` command or you can use [Extension auto-installer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started#Developing_without_cfx_run) to run the extension without restarting your browser.

Since the Firefox add-on SDK just uses standard web languages (HTML, JS, CSS), the question of whether to use an IDE or just a text editor (or even where to draw the line between the two) is just as contentious a debate as it is for normal web development. So have a look around the web for best IDE/text editor for web development and you'll see all the varying opinions people have on the subject.

My recommendation is to use the `cfx` or `jpm` tools mentioned above to `init` the project, which will create the `data` and `lib` folders and the `package.json` file that you need. Then use a text editor like Sublime Text to edit your JS, CSS, and HTML code. Then use one of the tools mentioned above to launch the extension.

Both Netbeans and Eclipse are mainly Java IDEs, and so I would recommend against them. If you feel you want something more like an IDE and less like a text editor, I would recommend [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Is there any link that explains the steps to install addon-SDK in Webstorm ?

Comment: There is no way of installing the SDK in Webstorm. You have to use the SDK through the command line/terminal.